# If $a,b,c$ are in Geometric Progression and$ a-b,c-a,b-c$ are in Harmonic Progression, then the value of $a+4b+c$ is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a,b,c$ are in Geometric Progression and $a-b$,$c-a$,$b-c$ are in Harmonic Progression, then the value of $a+4b+c$ is equal to?

The statements I could get are

1)$b^2=ac$
2)$(c-a)^2=2(b-a)(b-c)$

I get that $(a+4b+c)^2=24ac+6ab+6bc$.

how to proceed and get to the answer??Options given are 
a)1
b)0
3)2abc
d)b^2+ac

Comment: What is GP? General position? What is HP?

Comment: @user7530 Geometric/Harmonic Progression

Comment: geometric progression and harmonic progression

Comment: Can you explain your equation for [Harmonic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_(mathematics))? Wikipedia disagrees with you.

Comment: let say some x,y,z are in hp then 1/x,1/y,1/z are in ap then 2/y=1/x+1/y..I have just used this

Comment: Precisely, so it expands out to $2(a-b)(b-c) = (a-b)(c-a) + (c-a)(b-c)$. I do not see how you arrived at your 2nd equation directly.

Comment: we could also write it as 2xz/x+z=y..u will get it from here

Comment: @CalvinLin Factor out the $(c-a)$ from the right-hand side.

Comment: @CalvinLin also in ur eqn take (c-a) common in the right hand side u will get the same equation

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that you wrote the equation directly, as if it was a well known fact of harmonic progressions. Didn't realize that you manipulated it some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition for a harmonic progression is that

$$ \frac{1}{a-b} + \frac{1}{b-c} = \frac{ 2}{ c-a}. $$

Clearing denominators, we get

$$ a^2 -2b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2 bc - 4ac = 0. $$

This gives us 
$$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ac = 0 + 3b^2 + 6ac =9b^2.$$

Hence, either $ a+b+c = 3b$ or $a+b+c = -3b$.

Now, in the first case, since $a+c = 2b$ and $ac = b^2$, hence we must have $a=b=c$. This means that $a-b, c-a, b-c$ is not a harmonic progression.

Thus, we must have $a+b+c = - 3b$, or that $a+4b+c = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $b=ra$ and $c=r^2a$.  Then $c-a=\frac{2(a-b)(b-c)}{a-c}$, so $(c-a)^2=2(b-a)(b-c)$ and therefore $(r^2-1)^2 a^2=2(r-1)ar(1-r)a=-2r(r-1)^2a^2$.     Dividing by
$(r-1)^2a^2$ gives $(r+1)^2=-2r$ and therefore $r^2+4r+1=0$.  Thus $a+4b+c=a+4ra+r^2 a=a(r^2+4r+1)=0$.